Ubuntu installing process in windows
I have installed Ubuntu in my Windows 11 Pro using WSL, but in the folder it's having a ext4 file.


What is the question? Ubuntu needs a format of ext4 for its file system.

The file you are seeing is ext4.vhdx (Explorer isn't configured to show extensions), and it's the virtual SDD that the Ubuntu distribution is stored on. You'll notice that you are looking at an AppData subdirectory, meaning this is the data for the application, not the application itself.
To run Ubuntu, you'll typically just use the Start Menu as you do with all other applications. Start typing *"Ubuntu 24.04" and you'll find it in the list.
This will run it in the default terminal, which should be Microsoft's Windows Terminal (if not, install it).
In case there's any confusion, Ubuntu on WSL is a terminal-based distribution (the server version of Ubuntu, without graphical desktop).
